# Xcode 14 UnsafePointer.withMemoryRebound throwing EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP) during unit tests of unzip protocol

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gzip

Hellow!

I'm trying to run unit tests on a piece of code but I'm getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP) exception when the following code is executed:

```swift
/// Decompresses the data using the gzip deflate algorithm. Self is expected to be a gzip deflate
    /// stream according to [RFC-1952](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1952).
    /// - returns: uncompressed data
    func gunzip() -> Data?
    {
        // 10 byte header + data +  8 byte footer. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1952#section-2
        let overhead = 10 + 8
        guard count >= overhead else { return nil }


        typealias GZipHeader = (id1: UInt8, id2: UInt8, cm: UInt8, flg: UInt8, xfl: UInt8, os: UInt8)
        let hdr: GZipHeader = withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> GZipHeader in
            // +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
            // |ID1|ID2|CM |FLG|     MTIME     |XFL|OS |
            // +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
            return (id1: ptr[0], id2: ptr[1], cm: ptr[2], flg: ptr[3], xfl: ptr[8], os: ptr[9])
        }

        typealias GZipFooter = (crc32: UInt32, isize: UInt32)
        let ftr: GZipFooter = withUnsafeBytes { (bptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> GZipFooter in
            // +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
            // |     CRC32     |     ISIZE     |
            // +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
            return bptr.advanced(by: count - 8).withMemoryRebound(to: UInt32.self, capacity: 2) { ptr in
                return (ptr[0].littleEndian, ptr[1].littleEndian)
            }
        }

        // Wrong gzip magic or unsupported compression method
        guard hdr.id1 == 0x1f && hdr.id2 == 0x8b && hdr.cm == 0x08 else { return nil }

        let has_crc16: Bool = hdr.flg & 0b00010 != 0
        let has_extra: Bool = hdr.flg & 0b00100 != 0
        let has_fname: Bool = hdr.flg & 0b01000 != 0
        let has_cmmnt: Bool = hdr.flg & 0b10000 != 0

        let cresult: Data? = withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Data? in
            var pos = 10 ; let limit = count - 8

            if has_extra {
                pos += ptr.advanced(by: pos).withMemoryRebound(to: UInt16.self, capacity: 1) {
                    return Int($0.pointee.littleEndian) + 2 // +2 for xlen
                }
            }
            if has_fname {
                while pos < limit && ptr[pos] != 0x0 { pos += 1 }
                pos += 1 // skip null byte as well
            }
            if has_cmmnt {
                while pos < limit && ptr[pos] != 0x0 { pos += 1 }
                pos += 1 // skip null byte as well
            }
            if has_crc16 {
                pos += 2 // ignoring header crc16
            }

            guard pos < limit else { return nil }
            let config = (operation: COMPRESSION_STREAM_DECODE, algorithm: COMPRESSION_ZLIB)
            return perform(config, source: ptr.advanced(by: pos), sourceSize: limit - pos)
        }

        guard let inflated = cresult                                   else { return nil }
        guard ftr.isize == UInt32(truncatingIfNeeded: inflated.count)  else { return nil }
        guard ftr.crc32 == inflated.crc32().checksum                   else { return nil }
        return inflated
    }

fileprivate extension Data {
    func withUnsafeBytes<ResultType, ContentType>(_ body: (UnsafePointer<ContentType>) throws -> ResultType) rethrows -> ResultType
    {
        return try self.withUnsafeBytes({ (rawBufferPointer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) -> ResultType in
            return try body(rawBufferPointer.bindMemory(to: ContentType.self).baseAddress!)
        })
    }
}
```

This portion of code always throws the mentioned exception:

[image]

This problem has been happening consistently. This code has not been touched in 2 years, and it doesn't fail when running in a cloud pipeline (Azure) with MacOS 10.15

It fails on multiple MacOS devices running Monterrey (12.6) and Xcode 14.

Anyone has any thoughts on what can be causing it?

I know the problem is pretty vague but that's the only context I have.

Thanks

Comment: Is this on Apple silicon (an M1)?

Comment: No, its an Intel MacBook.

Comment: Are you recompiling the code on each machine you are testing it on?

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? I see the behavior of that function changed in 5.7: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0333-with-memory-rebound.md

Comment: Thanks @Lolindrath will take a look! This is promising.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippet you provided, there is no obvious error that would cause the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP) exception.
It seems that the error is related to the memory management, the code is using pointers, and it seems that the memory that `bptr` is pointing to is not valid or that it doesn't match the type specified in the `withMemoryRebound` function.

One possible cause of this issue could be that the code is expecting a specific memory layout or alignment that is not present on the newer version of macOS. There are few things you could try:

- Update the code to use the latest Swift syntax and features, this will help you to avoid deprecated methods and also help you to avoid pointer related errors.
- Run the code on an older version of macOS and Xcode to see if that resolves the issue.
- Check if there is any system library that is missing from the environment or if there are any system libraries that are outdated.
- Try running the code on a simulator or emulator and see if that resolves the issue, this will help you to understand if the problem is related to the specific device or the operating system version
- Try to use some debugging tools like the `lldb` to trace the problem and see which instruction is causing the error, this will help you to understand the problem and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Francis! Your suggestion #2 is what I did - the code runs fine on an older version of MacOS running on Azure Pipelines. I found the updated implementation of the gzip algorithm and will try updating my code with that. Thanks for the additional suggestions, will try the debugging tool!